# Video gallery using Facebook Video

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I am trying to create a video player with a playlist function similar to the one below. I would like to play my videos that I have uploaded to Facebook on my page.

Example: http://wistia.com/product/playlist

1. - What is the best way to link the video (I need a direct link with an extension)?
2. - I need to embed the [MP4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14) Facebook video version in order to support [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) devices. Currently the graph only grants temp access to MP4 links

Answer (score 0):

Using the graph API, you can HTTP Post: `fql?q=select vid,title,src,src_hq from video where owner=me()` to get a list of your videos.

Or `fql?q=select vid,title,src,src_hq from video where owner  in (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())` to get a list of videos uploaded by your friends.

If these links are temp links that expire, then you should query Facebook each time you want to play from the playlist.  Just ask your user for `offline_access` permission  :)